# 7 wires, 3 sources, switchable power in 2 wires - how to put it back?

Tags: electrical, wiring, light-fixture

I tried to mount a new lamp and it couldn't fit because of the [ceiling rose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceiling_rose) so I took it out to see what can be done.

Turns out that there are 7 wires coming from 3 different sources, 2 hot wires, depending on how I turn the electricity on / off at the panel. I also lost power in few power sockets in that room so I assume that the outlet was chaining the electricity.

2 of the 3 sources have 2 wires in them, while the 3rd has 3 wires. The sources with 2 wires are the ones which have the hot wires. It's an old building so I assume there is no ground wire among them. As for their color, 4 of them are white and 3 black.

I don't know what other info would be neccesary. Let me know if you need to know something else.

[image]

PS: I used one of those electrical screwdrivers to check which one is hot.

EDIT: More images

Wires:

[image]
[image]

The rose

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hey Red... the two hots, is that a ring circuit?  Or another circuit passing through?

Comment: OP what country or region are we in? The rose smells like Europe but the wire jacket colors do very much not.

Comment: @Harper You're right. I'm located in Denmak, Europe. I don't think the wires have ever been changed so that makes them ~ 80 years old.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to test out different combinations, blowing up a fuse in the process. In the end I gave up and called an electrician.

He figured it out by testing out which wires make a circuit with the wall plugs. He had some sort of multimeter for testing it.

I believe the wiring was done similar to the following diagram (while ignoring ground wires):

[image: Wiring Diagram]